# Powershell values within a loop losing their value

Tags: powershell

Forgive the title, I'm not really sure how to explain what I'm seeing.

Sample Code:

```
    $SampleValues = 1..5
    $Result = "" | Select ID
    $Results = @()  

    $SampleValues | %{
        $Result.ID = $_
        $Results += $Result
    }

$Results
```

This is fairly straightforward:

- Create an array with 5 numbers to be used in a loop
- Create a temp variable with a NoteProperty called ID
- Create an empty array to store results
- Iterate through each of the 5 numbers assigning them to a temp variable then appending that to an array.

The expected result is 1,2,3,4,5 but when run this returns 5,5,5,5,5

This is a barebones example taken from a much more complex script and I'm trying to figure out why the result is what it is. In each iteration all elements that have already been added to $Results have their values updated to the most recent value. I've tested forcing everything to $Script: or $Global: scope and get the same results.

The only solution I've found is the following, which moves the $Result declaration into the loop.

```
    $SampleValues = 1..5
    $Results = @()

$SampleValues | %{
    $Result = "" | Select ID
    $Result.ID = $_
    $Results += $Result
    }
```

This works (you get 1,2,3,4,5 as your results). It looks like $Results is just holding multiple references to a singular $Result object but why does moving this into the loop fix the problem? In this example $Result is a string so perhaps it is creating a new object each iteration but even when I forced $Result to be an integer (which shouldn't recreate a new object since an integer isn't immutable like a string) it still fixed the problem and I got the result I expected.

If anybody has any insight into exactly why this fixes the problem I've be very curious. There are plenty of alternatives for me to implement but not understanding specifically why this works this way is bugging me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It fixes the problem by moving into the loop because then you are then creating a new $Result object each time rather than changing a value on the same one (referenced 5 times in the array).

It doesn't have anything to do with whether you use `"" | Select ID` or `123 | Select ID` because that just becomes a sort of property on the PSCustomObject, which is still a reference type rather than a value type.

Remember, Powershell is all .NET on the inside. Here is some C# that's analogous to what Powershell is doing in your first example that resulted in all 5s (hopefully you know C#):

```
var SampleValues = new []{1,2,3,4,5};
var Result = new CustomObject(){ ID = "" };
var Results = new List<Object>();

foreach (var _ in SampleValues) {
    Result.ID = _;
    Results.Add(Result);
}
```

Hopefully you can see how moving `var Result = new CustomObject(){ ID = "" }` inside the `foreach` loop would make it work better, and the same concept holds true in Powershell.

Comment: Joel, thank you for the comment.

Integers are value types.

I tried 'Result = 0 | Select ID' and both Result and ID were Int32. This is what confused me because I still got 5,5,5,5,5.

Comment: Forgive the double comment, I can't seem to edit my initial reply.

This is what I'm referring to. If $Result and ID are both Int32 then they're value types, not reference types, so what is the object reference that $Results is storing?

$Result | gm

  TypeName: Selected.System.Int32

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
ID          NoteProperty System.Int32 ID=1

Comment: If you do `$Result = 0 | Select ID`, `$Result.GetType()` returns `PSCustomObject` with a basetype of `System.Object`. `$Result.ID` should be `null` initially. If you assign an integer (`$Result.ID = 0`), `$Result.GetType()` is still the same, but now `$Result.ID.GetType()` returns `Int32`, basetype `System.ValueType`.

Comment: Now I see why you thought `$Result` was of type `Int32`. And from searching, you're not the only one to find this behavior strange. However, it is indeed a reference type, no matter what `Get-Member` is saying.

Comment: Ah! You're absolutely right. I was pretty sure this was a reference/value problem as I mentioned in my original comment but I just couldn't see what the reference type object was coming from, given the results of Get-Member. Doing $Result.GetType() in fact shows it is a PSCustomObject, so this makes complete sense now.

Just needed another pair of eyes on it, thank you very much!

Comment: Ah-HA! When `$Result | Get-Member` is displaying "TypeName: Selected.System.Int32", it is displaying the original type that was used in the `Select-Object` to create the `PSCustomObject`.

Comment: Good observation. With just $Result = 0 you get System.Int32, instead of Selected.System.Int32. In that case GetType shows it as a Int32 and not PSCustomObject. To be safe though I think I'll probably start assuming PowerShell is treating everything as an object, even scalar datatypes.

Comment: Here is some more explanation.  PowerShell can add properties and members to objects using its Extended Type System.  But you can't modify normal .NET objects like that.  So PowerShell wraps them with a PSObject that does the magic.  Sometimes you have this object directly (like after Select-Object).  And sometimes it is transparent to you, like with these two examples.  `ps | select -first 1 | gm` versus `(ps | select -first 1).PSBase | gm`

Answer (score 1):

*In this example $Result is a string so perhaps it is creating a new object each iteration but even when I forced $Result to be an integer (which shouldn't recreate a new object since an integer isn't immutable like a string) it still fixed the problem and I got the result I expected.*

Actually, in your example $Result is not a string.  It is a generic object with one propery (ID) that is a string.

Powershell variables come in 2 types - value and reference. A string or integer is passed by value, an object is passed by reference.  By addind $result to $results 5 times you got 5 refereneces to the one $result object, not 5 different objects.

If we add the $result.id property (an integer / value type) to $results instead of the $result object we get:

```
 $SampleValues = 1..5
     $Result = "" | Select ID
     $Results = @()  

     $SampleValues | %{
         $Result.ID = $_
         $Results += $Result.ID
     }

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```